# Using * in main() parameters for command-line calculator

Tags: c, command-line, strcmp

I'm doing a homework problem which is to create a calculator using the argc and argv[] parameters in the main function.

What we were supposed to do, and I did, was to create a char pointer array containing the operators I want to use.
this is what I have:

```
const int OTabMax = 10;
const char *OTab[] = {
                      "+",
                      "-",
                      "*",
                      "/",
                      "quad",
                      "wurz",
                      "sinR",
                      "sinG",
                      "cosR",
                      "cosG" 
                     };

int OTabCheck(char S[]) // char *S
{
    int n;
    for (n = 0; n < OTabMax; n++){
        if (strcmp(S, OTab[n]) == 0) {break;}
    }
return n;
}
```

It returns a number depending on which operator was used, which goes into a switch case where the calculation is done.

looks like this:

```
switch(key){

            case 0:
            break;

            case 1:
            break;

            case 2:
                x = atof(argv[1]);
                y = atof(argv[3]);
                z = 0;
                z = x*y;
                printf("%f * %f = %f\n",x,y,z);
            break;

            case 3-8;
            break;

            case 9:
            break;

            default: printf("Wrong input!\n"); exit(0); break;
        }
```

The case in question is case 2: which whenever I do a calculation like calling the program through the terminal with `./"program_name" 2 * 2`

it printf's 2.000000 * 0.000000 = 2.000000

here is the MRE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

    const int OTabMax = 10;
    const char *OTab[] = {
                            "+",
                            "-",
                            "*",
                            "/",
                            "quad",
                            "wurz",
                            "sinR",
                            "sinG",
                            "cosR",
                            "cosG" };

int OTabCheck(char S[]) // char *S
{
    int n;
    for (n = 0; n < OTabMax; n++){
        if (strcmp(S, OTab[n]) == 0) {break;}
    }
    return n;
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;
    float z = 0;
    int key = 0;

    if(argc < 3){
        exit(0);
    }

    if(argc == 4){

    key = OTabCheck(argv[2]);

    }else if(argc == 3){
    key = OTabCheck(argv[1]);

    }
        switch(key){

            case 2:
                x = atof(argv[1]);
                y = atof(argv[3]);
                z = 0;
                z = x*y;
                printf("%f * %f = %f\n",x,y,z);
                exit(0);
            break;

            default: printf("Wrong input!\n"); exit(0); break;
        }

}
```

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: What is `case 3-8;` ??

Comment: Probably the shell replaces `*` with all file names. Try `./program_name 2 '*' 2`. You can print `argv[1]` etc. to find out if this is the case.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Well it’s right there, sorry if I wasn’t clear. What I mean is that when I write something like  ./”program_name” 2 + 2 it outputs it properly as 4 but if I do ./“program_name” 2 * 2 it gives 0 as the output. However when compiling I don’t have any errors. Should I post the program?

Comment: It's not there - no complete program that can be copy/pasted and compiled. For example it does not show if you check `argc` or how you call `OTabCheck()`

Comment: @Bodo yea this is it works with the ' ' marks. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @WeatherVane oh sorry, yea it does check for enough argumments I can edit in some more information :)

Comment: You probably have your answer, but for future reference the [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is *de rigueur*. It stops a flurry of questions, and typos introduced while posting.

Comment: Alright, I'm quite new here so sorry about that. yea I have my answer but I'll add the MRE to clarify for future references. :)

Comment: @Omorio Instead of answering in comments, **[edit] your question and add all information there.**